# How to stop quantity being added back to stock when an order is cancelled in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, inventory

I need to stop decreasing the stock quantity when an order is placed and reduce the stock only on successful payment because there are lot abandoned transactions on my site. I found an article to do this link, which says how to credit back the quantity to the product on redirect action and the decrease it on successful response action.

Also I am running a cron to cancel the abandoned orders. When the orders are cancelled the quantities get added back to product stock.

My problem is, how do I overwrite the cancel action so that the product stock is not updated when an abandoned order is cancelled?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop this by configuring from admin panel.Go to:
system->configuration->inventory->stock options->Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled
change this value to "No".

You can also stop to decrease the stock quantity on order placed:
system->configuration->inventory->stock options->Decrease Stock When Order is Placed

Hope this will solve your problem